# Python Twisted deferToThread function is not working as expected

Tags: python, twisted

My goal here is to make a simple server handling TCP message like "process My String" that send "My String" to be processed by a quite time taking operation called (here slowFunction). Here I'm calling this function through deferToThread but nothing seems to happened : the defered's callback messages doesn't show up anywhere (breakpoints show it's never called) and the print in the function aren't displayed (breakpoints show it's never called)

```
from twisted import protocols
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import threads, protocol, reactor
from twisted.application import service, internet
import re
import time

def slowFunction(arg):
    print "starting process"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "processed "+arg

class MySimpleServer(basic.LineReceiver):

    PROCESS_COMMAND = "process (.*)" #re pattern
    processFunction = slowFunction
    clients = []

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Client connected"
        MySimpleServer.clients.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Client gone"
        MySimpleServer.clients.remove(self)

    def onProcessDone(self):
        self.message("Process done")

    def onError(self):
        self.message("Process fail with error")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        processArgumentResult = re.search(MySimpleServer.PROCESS_COMMAND, line)
        if not processArgumentResult == None:
            processArgument = processArgumentResult.groups()[0] 
            deferred = threads.deferToThread(MySimpleServer.processFunction, processArgument)
            deferred.addCallback(self.onProcessDone)
            deferred.addErrback(self.onError)
            self.message("processing your request")
        else:
            print "Unknown message line: "+line

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = MySimpleServer
    factory.client = []

    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Small unrelated point: Don't compare equality to `None`, just use `is None` or `is not None` as needed.

Comment: Ok, can you please explain mewhy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got some help by the guys of [twisted irc](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/twisted)

The points are : the callback (onProcessDone and onError) are supposed to take a result argument, and the function called by deferToThread will receive self as an argument (it should one of the MySimpleServer class' method).

The final code is now :

```
from twisted import protocols
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet import threads, protocol, reactor
from twisted.application import service, internet
import re
import time

def slowFunction(arg):
    print "starting process"
    time.sleep(20)
    print "processed "+arg

class MySimpleServer(basic.LineReceiver):

    PROCESS_COMMAND = "process (.*)" #re pattern
    clients = []

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "Client connected"
        MySimpleServer.clients.append(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "Client gone"
        MySimpleServer.clients.remove(self)

    def onProcessDone(self, result):
        self.message("Process done")

    def onError(self, result):
        self.message("Process fail with error")

    def processFunction(self, processArgument):
        slowFunction(processArgument)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        processArgumentResult = re.search(MySimpleServer.PROCESS_COMMAND, line)
        if not processArgumentResult == None:
            processArgument = processArgumentResult.groups()[0] 
            deferred = threads.deferToThread(self.processFunction, processArgument)
            deferred.addCallback(self.onProcessDone)
            deferred.addErrback(self.onError)
            self.message("processing your request")
        else:
            print "Unknown message line: "+line

    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = MySimpleServer
    factory.client = []

    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way you could've done this is with `staticmethod`; this is the *only* legitimate use for it.

```
class MySimpleServer(basic.LineReceiver):
    processFunction = staticmethod(slowFunction)
```